# Dropwizard Jersey client Multipart http request

Tags: java, rest, http, dropwizard, jersey-client

Dropwizard (Version 0.8.2) uses Jersey internally to provide HTTP client. I am using this client to send a Multipart POST request to an external Rest Endpoint to a SMS Service. Code is given below but it doesn't seems to be working because i am not receiving any message through this method also it does not throw any error.
**URI** for the first sample is http://enterprise.com/GatewayAPI/rest?userid=%s&password=%s&method=xlsUpload&filetype=zip&msg_type=TEXT&auth_scheme=PLAIN&v=1.1

```
FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart(fileName, file,
                                                        MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
      FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();

      multiPart.field("fileName", fileName).bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart);
      Entity<FormDataMultiPart> entity =
          Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType());// MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)

      Client tenacityClient = TenacityJerseyClientBuilder
          .builder(AppDependencyKeys.BULK_SMS)
          .usingTimeoutPadding(Duration.milliseconds(500)).build(client)
          .register(MultiPartFeature.class);

      Invocation invocation = getResourceBuilder(tenacityClient, uri).buildPost(entity);
      Future<Response> futureResponse = invocation.submit();
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

      futureResponse.get();
```

But the same works with below method when i use Apache Commons Httpclient. working code for the same is given below.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    PostMethod method = new
        PostMethod("http://enterprise.com/GatewayAPI/rest");
    Part[] parts = {
        new StringPart("method", "xlsUpload"),
        new StringPart("userid", "*******"),
        new StringPart("password", "*******"),
        new StringPart("filetype", "zip"),
        new StringPart("v", "1.1"),
        new StringPart("auth_scheme", "PLAIN"),
        new FilePart(file.getName(), file)
    };
    method.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, method.getParams()));
    int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
    log.info("Status code: {}", statusCode);
```

But i want to use the first way as that suits my infrastructure better.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Question is why first code is not working while the second one is working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set up properly media type for entity. Currently, you created new FormDataMultiPart but, you did not set and media type and it uses "text/plain" y default.

So, you should set up MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE to your FormDataMultiPart as media type.

Comment: I tried doing it but i get following exception..

'caught Exception while processing request javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/octet-stream, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart.'